# ui-view won't render template two levels in, Could not resolve from state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been struggling a bit with understanding angular's ui-router.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is loading of template's within a a ui-view which is  2 levels in.

The main page, which incorporates Login and Registration looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="anonymous"></div>
    <div ui-view="home"></div>
</body>
```

Within the `anonymous` `ui-view` I render my Login and Registration templates accordingly.

Once the user is logged in, I render the `frame.html` template within the `home`  `ui-view`.

Inside the `frame.html` template we have a menu system for the dashboard which contains the navigation for all `states` inside.

Also, `frame.html` holds the deeper `ui-view` called `home_content` which will render each template within it.

```
<div id="page-inner">
    <!--UI RENDER FOR DASHBOARD HOME INNER CONTENT -->
    <div ui-view="home_content"></div>
</div>
```

In a previous question regarding this, I was able to render the initial content within `home_content` with the frame around it (menus) but the links in the menu continue to yield:

`Error: Could not resolve 'user.invoice' from state 'user.home'`

Here is my full `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module("Application", [
    'ui.router',
    'ngMessages',
    'ui-notification',
    'angularSpinner',
    'accountModule',
    'dashboardModule'


]);

app.constant("AccessLevels", {
    anon: 0,
    user: 1
});

app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "AccessLevels", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, AccessLevels) {

    /* ANONYMOUSE USERS */
    $stateProvider
        .state('anon', {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            data: {
                access: AccessLevels.anon
            }
        })
        .state('anon.login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: { 
                'anonymous@': {
                    templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/account/login.html',
                    controller: 'loginCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('anon.register', {
            url: '/register',
            views: {
                'anonymous@': {
                    templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/account/registration.html',
                    controller: 'registerCtrl'
                }
            }
        });

    /* AUTHENTICATED USERS */
    $stateProvider
        .state('user', {
            abstract: true,
            data: {
                access: AccessLevels.user
            },
            views: {
                'home': {
                    template: '<div ui-view="home"></div>',
                }
            }
        })
        .state('user.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'home@': {
                    templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/home/frame.html'
                },
                'home_content@user.home': {
                    templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/home/dashboard/index.html',
                    controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
                },
                'home_content@user.delivery': {
                    templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/home/deliveries/deliveries.html',
                    controller: 'deliveryCtrl'
                },
                'home_content@user.invoice': {
                    templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/home/invoices/invoices.html',
                    controller: 'invoiceCtrl'
                },
                'home_content@user.order': {
                    templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/home/orders/orders.html',
                    controller: 'orderCtrl'
                }
            }
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}]);

app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, Auth) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (!Auth.authorize(toState.data.access)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('anon.login');
        }
    });
});
```

In my `frame.html` I have the menu system, here's one of the links:

```
<a class="active-menu" ui-sref="user.home">Home</a>
```

Am I setting this up correctly? How do I about rendering those templates in the most inner `ui-view`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is related to mismatch of

1. defined view targets (ui-view) and
2. views targeting them

As we can read:

> ... Also, `frame.html` holds the deeper `ui-view` called **`'home_content'`** which will render each template within it...

So, there is exactly one target. One target named **`'home_content'`**

But in the state `views : {}` we can see many views... trying to reach the same target:

```
.state('user.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'home@': {
            templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/home/frame.html'
        },
        'home_content@user.home': {
            ....
        },
        'home_content@user.delivery': {
            ....
        }
        'home_content@user.invoice': {
            ....
         }
        ...
```

As we can see now, we target one name view **'home_content'**. It won't work, unless it exist in the hierarchy (parent has `home_content`, grand parent has `home_content`). Then it would be like

```
.state('grandParent.parent.current', {
    views: {
        '' : { template: '<div ui-view="home_content"></div>' },
        ...
        // I. here we target current state
        'home_content@grandparent.parent.current': {
            ....
        },

        // II. here we target our parent, which would be the same
        'home_content@grandparent.parent': {
        // as we use relative names
        'home_content': {
            ....
        }

        // III. here we target grandParent
        'home_content@grandparent': {
            ....
         }
        ...
```

So, that is how the absolute naming works:

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of viewname@statename, where viewname is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. contact.item. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

What would work in our scenario? well we have to use more targets inside of  **frame.html**

```
<div ui-view="home_content"></div>
<div ui-view="other1"></div>
<div ui-view="other2"></div>
<div ui-view="other3"></div>
```

And then we can target them:

```
.state('user.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'home@': {
            templateUrl: 'Client/scripts/app/partials/home/frame.html'
        },
        'home_content@user.home': {
            ....
        },
        'other1@user.home': {
            ....
        }
        'other2@user.home': {
        ...
```

If still not so clear, I would suggest to observe this tremendous piece of code:

- [contact.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js), which is an essential, **the best ever documented**, part of
- [sample app](http://sample%20app)

Comment: Thank you Radim, I got it setup the way you demonstrated but the views all load at once. All views are loading their corresponding template as soon as i login. I wanted to be able to load them on demand individually via the menu. Initial login displays dashboard template, clicking on the Orders menu will then render OrdersTemplate instead.. So on...

Comment: I was able to identify where my issue occurred thanks to your detailed break down. I'm able to successfully load content on demand on just one `ui-view` container without issues. The trick for me was to create another state that has a parent of my `user.home` state. By doing this, i was then able to target the same view within `@user.home` and load content as needed.  I truly appreciate your help! I will accept your answer and add to it.

Comment: Great to see that you made it. When I started to answer, I was not sure which way I should go... multi views or multi states. Now, you have my description of multi views and you found your solution for multi states. Amazing ;) Enjoy UI-Router

Comment: YUP! :) Thanks again, appreciate your help very much. Take care